# Django model pre save for custom ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model with a many-to-many relationship. In a `pre_save` signal i want to preprocess the instance data:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Book)
def pre_save_tags(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # tags is a many-to-many relation
    print instance.tags
```

`tags` is set in a `SelectMultiple` field. Therefore, it has multiple values.

### The problem

```
ValueError: 'Book' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

1. How can i get the tags of the yet unsaved instance?
2. How can i change the tags before saving them?

I am not limited to `pre_save`. If there are better solutions, i am all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I am sure there are more elegant ways. Please give me some pointers or provide a better solution if you know how to improve the code:

```
class ManyToManyTagField(ManyToManyField):

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            'form_class': TagField,
        }
        return super(ManyToManyTagField, self).formfield(**defaults)

    def save_form_data(self, instance, data):
        tags = []
        for tag_id in data:
            autocompletedTag = tag_id.find('___')
            if autocompletedTag > 0:
                parts = tag_id.split('___')
                tags.append(parts[0])
            else:
                newTag = Tag(name=tag_id, category=TagCategory.objects.get(name='New'))
                newTag.save()
                tags.append(newTag.id)

        return super(ManyToManyTagField, self).save_form_data(instance, tags)
```

The relevant part is the method `save_form_data`.

Here are the other classes, just for the sake of completeness.

TagWidget:

```
class TagWidget(SelectMultiple):
    """
    Widget for Tag input fields.
    """
    queryset = []

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
        final_attrs['class'] = 'tag-input'

        selectedTags = []
        if value:
            for tag_id in value:
                if isinstance(tag_id, (int, long)) or tag_id.isdigit():
                    tag_name = Tag.objects.get(pk=tag_id).name
                    selectedTags.append({ 'value': str(tag_id) + '___' + tag_name, 'label': tag_name })
                else:
                    autocompletedTag = tag_id.find('___')
                    if autocompletedTag > 0:
                        parts = tag_id.split('___')
                        selectedTags.append({ 'value': parts[0] + '___' + parts[1], 'label': parts[1] })
                    else:
                        selectedTags.append({ 'value': tag_id, 'label': tag_id })

        allTags = []
        for tag in self.queryset:
            allTags.append({ 'value': str(tag.id) + '___' + str(tag.name), 'label': str(tag.name) });

        allTagsJson = simplejson.dumps(allTags)

        return render_to_string('form/tagwidget.html',
                                {'attrs': flatatt(final_attrs), 'selectedTags': selectedTags, 'allTags': allTagsJson})
```

TagField:

```
class TagField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    widget = TagWidget

    def __init__(self, queryset, *args, **kwargs):
        self.widget.queryset = queryset
        super(TagField, self).__init__(queryset, *args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self, value):
        if self.required and not value:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'])
        elif not self.required and not value:
            return []
        if not isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['list'])
        # Since this overrides the inherited ModelChoiceField.clean
        # we run custom validators here
        self.run_validators(value)
        return value
```

tagwidget.html:

```
{% autoescape off %}
<ul{{ attrs }}>
{% for tag in selectedTags %}
    <li tagValue="{{ tag.value }}">{{ tag.label }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
var autocompletionData = {{ allTags }};
</script>
{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the object is new, and is not saved yet. There for it has not got a primary-key. If you save a object that has been saved before, this error should not happen.

Why don't you use post_save. In post_save the object has been saved, and therefore has a primary key. If you have to use pre_save you can check if instance.id exist. If it don't exist, you can't have any tags (since a object has to have a primary id for ManyToMany-fields to work (hence the exception))

To test for a primary-key, you can do something like this:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Book)
def pre_save_tags(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # tags is a many-to-many relation
    if instance.id:
        print instance.tags
```

Comment: the problem with post_save is that saving the object throws an error because he might try to save tags that don't exist yet. therefore i need to check for new tags BEFORE saving the object